# AngularJS : How to use one resolve for all the routes of my application

Tags: angularjs

I would like to resolve the promise that loads the current user for all the pages of my application. 
Currently I repeat the resolve in every `$routeProvider.when()` of my routes.

```
  $routeProvider.when('/users/edit/:userId', {
  templateUrl: 'app/app/assets/partials/user-edit.html', 
  controller: 'UserEditController',
  resolve:{  
    'currentUser':function( UserService){            
        return UserService.getCurrentUser();
      }
  }
  });  

  $routeProvider.when('/staff_profil/edit', {
  templateUrl: 'app/app/assets/partials/profil-edit.html', 
  controller: 'ProfilEditController',
  resolve:{  
    'currentUser':function( UserService){            
        return UserService.getCurrentUser();
      }
  }
 });
```

My goal is to resolve my current user for all the routes without repetition.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could always wrap the existing when method on the [`$routeProvider`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider) with your own implementation.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute'])
   .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

      var originalWhen = $routeProvider.when;

      $routeProvider.when = function(path, route){

         route.resolve = {
            'currentUser':function( UserService){            
              return UserService.getCurrentUser();
            }
         };

         return originalWhen(path, route);
      };   

   }]);
```

You probably want to add some error checking in there, and use something like [underscores `defaults`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) method instead of just overwriting the existing resolve property, but at least this way you can guarantee all your routes will have what you want.

It's also easy enough to wrap this up into a helper method.

Comment: This looks great, but I get `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ... due to: $routeProvider.when(...) is undefined`, even if all the override method does is `return originalWhen(path, route);` Instead, I appended a new method, `$routeProvider.accessWhen`, which can `return $routeProvider.when(path, route);`, and call `.accessWhen` instead of `.when` in my routes setup.

Comment: wouln't the 'currentUser' resolve be overwritten if you add the resolve-property in the actual route? Maybe route.resolve = route.resolve || { }; route.resolve.currentUser = ... would be better?

Comment: Can you do something similar wiith ui-router ?

Answer (score 28):

For completeness, here is the whole solution, using angular instead of underscore, with a chainable 'when'.  Nothing new in this code, just combined a bunch of the answers above.

```
var originalWhen = $routeProvider.when;

    $routeProvider.when = function(path, route) {
        route.resolve || (route.resolve = {});
        angular.extend(route.resolve, {
            CurrentUser : function(User) {
                return User.current();
            }
        });

        return originalWhen.call($routeProvider, path, route);
    };
```

Comment: This should be the right answer. For me the accepted answer throws error when I don't use `.call`

Answer (score 4):

The @Josh answer is correct, except you have to invoke *originalWhen* function differently:

```
originalWhen.call($routeProvider, path, route);
```

Answer (score 3):

Both @N13 and I could not make [@Josh's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19938307/404699) work.  But this did work for me:

```
    module.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.accessWhen = function(path, route){
            route.resolve || (route.resolve = {});
            route.resolve.language = "something"
            return $routeProvider.when(path, route);
        };
    }]);
```

use with:

```
$routeProvider
        .accessWhen('/login', {
           ...
        });
```

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution to me

Answer (score 2):

I found that this case much better:

```
angular.extend({}, $routeProvider, {
  when: function(path, route) {
    route.resolve || (route.resolve = {});
    route.resolve = angular.merge({}, route.resolve, {
      chef: 'OrganizationCheckerProvider'
    });
    return $routeProvider.when(path, route);
  }
});
```

Comment: When the question is in javascript it should be answered in javascript.<br> This also use underscore... which he/she might not use

Comment: Endless, ok, changed to JS. 
lodash/underscore is preferred by me here, because it have excellent deep merge. He/she can try alternatives for lodash/underscore if not use.

Comment: AngularJS has [angular.merge(destination, source)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge) which looks similar to the lodash implementation `_.merge()`.

Answer (score 0):

For the people stuck with old code bases.

```
const _when = $routeProvider.when;
$routeProvider.when = (path, route) => _when.call($routeProvider, path, {
  ...route,
  resolve: {
    ...route.resolve,
    'currentUser': [ 'UserService', UserService => UserService.getCurrentUser() ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining all answers together

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            var originalWhen = $routeProvider.when;

            $routeProvider.when = function (path, route) {
                route.resolve || (route.resolve = {});
                angular.extend(route.resolve, {
                    CurrentUser: ['User', function (User) {
                        return User.current();
                    }]
                });
                return originalWhen.call($routeProvider, path, route);
            };
        }]);
```