# AngularJS ng-src and ng-attr-src don't work in IMG tag

Tags: angularjs, image, binding, src

I'm attempting to load an image from a URL in data being returned from MongoDB. On my user's profile editing page, they can edit certain details like their email address, and their user profile image. The email address data is binding well, however the ng-src for their profile image never resolves, so it's always blank, even though the user object contains the correct URL to which it should be binding.

HTML in question:

```
<div ng-controller="userCtrl">
  <img ng-src="{{currentUser.profileImage}}" src="{{currentUser.profileImage}}" class="img-responsive" alt="Profile Image"/>
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" ng-model="currentUser.name"/>
</div>
```

AngularJS call to init the data in my controller:

```
function UserCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $timeout, userService) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    userService.getCurrentUser().then(function(dataResponse) {
      if (dataResponse.data) {
        dataResponse.data.profileImage = "images/" + dataResponse.data.profileImage;
        userService.setCurrentUser(dataResponse.data);
        $scope.currentUser = dataResponse.data;
      }
    });
  }
  $timeout($scope.init());
}
```

I have tried every permutation of brackets, function calls, and delayed loading method that I could find reference to (hence the timeout usage there). I'm stumped on why currentUser.name would resolve fine, but currentUser.profileImage does not. I have no idea what on earth I'm missing to make this work like it's supposed to. Any assistance would be much appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should utilize the resolve method in ngRoute to make sure your data is resolved instead of using $timeout.

What I think is happening here is that since currentUser.profileImage is a string (which is a primitive in javascript), there is no 2-way binding happening therefore even though your function is resolving, the ui already has computed it as undefined. Using resolve in ngRoute will make sure that your page will not load until everything you need is resolved.

```
.when("/user", {
    templateUrl: "users.html",
    controller: "UserCtrl",
    resolve: {
        currentUser: function(userService){
            var currentUser = null;
            userService.getCurrentUser().then(function(dataResponse) {
                if (dataResponse.data) {
                    dataResponse.data.profileImage = "images/" + dataResponse.data.profileImage;
                    userService.setCurrentUser(dataResponse.data);
                    currentUser = dataResponse.data;
                }
            });

            return currentUser;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your controller you can simply do this and leave you view the same since ngRoute will handle the resolving:

```
function UserCtrl($scope, currentUser) {
    $scope.currentUser = currentUser;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Long. Thank you for the swift response! I have implemented this as you described, and it makes sense that this could be the problem, however I will need this to resolve for every page in all my routes (the username is on every page, if the user logs in). Is there an easy way to do that without duplicate code blocks and a resolve in each routeProvider.when assignment? Thank you very much, again!

Comment: I believe I have found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937751/angular-how-use-one-resolve-for-all-the-routes-of-my-application ... I will report back if it solves my problem, because I'll need to implement this fix before I can test the one you've posted.

Comment: The currentUser variable being passed to UserCtrl is "undefined". Something about the resolve code block isn't returning correctly, because I can see the correct user data being logged out if I drop a console.log into the getCurrentUser().then(... block.

Comment: It turns out that I have multiple things wrong, and on top of that, ngRoute isn't flexible enough for what I'm trying to do. I found out that I needed to inject the resolve variable into the UserCtrl function definition, not have ng-controller for UserCtrl assigned anywhere in the HTML, and $routeProvider doesn't support multiple controllers per view/template. Although, I could use directives or some other work-around. I'm going to look into ui-router as a potential replacement. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Its definitely possible to do this via ngRoute but ui-router is also an option, and its also my preferred routing module. In the case of the ui-router, I would create a state like so:

    .state('root', {
       resolve: {resolve code here}
    });

and then for all of your other states you can simply do:

    .state('otherState',
        parent: 'root');

This basically will evaluate the root state first and resolve the user.

Comment: Long, that's exactly the path I've taken :) It will be easier for me to come back to the routing code for ui.router and understand what I was doing and why, I think. Thank you, again.