# Pass authentication information from MVC into angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

My project uses MVC to deliver the initial markup of my site

The MVC controller is super simple:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have my `ng-app` tag, bundling, and `@RenderBody` in a layout view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myAppName">
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/aBundle")
</body>
</html>
```

And my Index view is stripped down as simple as possible:

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

My angular app.ts file looks like this:

```
module app {
    var main = angular.module("myAppName", ["ngRoute", "breeze.angular"]);

    main.config(routeConfig);

    routeConfig.$inject = ["$routeProvider"];
    function routeConfig($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider): void {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/home",
            {
                templateUrl: "app/views/homeView.html",
                controller: "HomeController as vm"
            })
            .when("/itemDetail/:itemId",
            {
                templateUrl: "app/views/itemDetailView.html",
                controller: "ItemDetailController as vm"
            })
            .when("/addItem",
            {
                templateUrl: "app/views/addItemView.html",
                controller: "AddItemController as vm"
            })
            .when("/login",
            {
                templateUrl: "app/views/loginView.html",
                controller: "LoginController as vm"
            })
            .otherwise("/home");
    }
}
```

I can inspect the Request sent by the user in the MVC controller, or in the Razor view using `@Request.IsAuthenticated` to see if the user is logged in, but what is the best way to pass this information to my angular app so that I can properly route the user to a login page when they first sign on, but skip the login page if they have an active session on the server?

The research I have done to try and figure this out has suggested to me that I probably need to create an angular service to store a boolean value regarding whether the user is authenticated or not. Then, I need to add some code to check this service for every route using `$routeChangeStart`, and redirecting to the login page only when necessary. I have looked at many examples, but can't quite put the pieces together in the context of my own application.

Could someone help me connect the dots, please?

Comment: You want angular to make a call to your MVC controller asking for this information!! So you could have a service called in your `app.run(function () {})` which calls a controller action that simply returns you a bool.

Comment: You can do something as simple as store the appropriate value in a hidden field in the template view markup. You should be able to test your "is logged in" logic by binding to the $routeChangeStart event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a project that I'm not using razor. Only html and angular in the views. So... What I did is:

I created a directive "appWrapper" that holds the layout. Inside of it there is a section that has the ng-view.
This directive uses a controller, the AuthCtrl, and this controller uses a service, the AuthService.
Because of this, I have access to everything that's inside this controller in the entire html. So I could say ng-click="vm.logout()" in an item in the sidebar, for example.
This "AuthService" has some methods that can be called by the controller. Login and logout being 2 of them.
When I execute login, I set some cookies with some information I get back from my controller.
When I logout, I remove these cookies.
On the app.js, where my routes are, I have I .run at the end that checks these cookies every time the location (url) is going to be changed. If they exist, it lets the user continue. If not, it redirects the user to the login.

Did it help? If needed, I can post the code for you to use as example.

No need to create an action inside a controller for checking this. It would require your application to go to the server, back to the browser, back to the server and back to the browser for every action the user takes. This is not good.

Comment: `No need to create an action inside a controller for checking this. It would require your application to go to the server, back to the browser, back to the server and back to the browser for every action the user takes. This is not good.` You can easily cache inside the javascript client, so this is never a problem

Comment: I just preferred this way. So I can stay logged based on the cookie expiration, instead of ending the session every time the browser is closed, but you're right. I'm sorry.  And, yes, he should always use authorize.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you would do it along the lines of below:

MVC controller:

```
[Authorize] // Make sure we're authorising the whole controller.
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult IsLoggedIn()
    {
        return Json(this.Request.IsAuthenticated); 
        // you may need allow get as the second parameter
    }
}
```

Angular:

```
app.factory('ProfileService', function ($http) {
    var service = {
        isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
    };

    return service;

    function isLoggedIn() {
        return $http.get('Profile/IsLoggedIn').then(function (response) {
            return response.data; // this depends on what the response object looks like
        });
    }
});

app.run(function (ProfileService, $location) {
    ProfileService.isLoggedIn().then(function (isLoggedIn) {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            $location.path('/unauthorised'); // just redirect them to the unauthorised route.
        }
    });
});
```

This means that everytime your app runs it will check to see whether you are logged in. You can also use this profile service to go grab other information about the user! And you can pull this service into any other module you wish to perform this kind stuff.

Remember that it is pointless trying to secure the javascript because it is run in a sandbox. But always make sure that you use `[Authorize]` attributes in your MVC code so that the server is always enforcing Authorisation and Authentication.

Before anyone says this isn't Typescript, any Javascript is also valid Typescript. I leave it to the user to put in the type defs.

## -- More Info --

You can add a `x`min cache expiry on the is logged in or store these details into local storage if you are constantly requesting the information:

```
app.factory('ProfileService', function ($http, $q) {
    var service = {
        isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
    };

    var cacheExpiries = {
        loggedIn: { value: null, expiry: null }
    };

    return service;

    function isLoggedIn() {
        var cacheObj = cacheExpiries['loggedIn'];
        var useCache = false;
        if (cacheObj.expiry) {
            useCache = new Date() < cacheObj.expiry;
        } 

        if (useCache) { 
            // because http returns a promise we need to 
            // short circuit function with a promise
            return $q(function (res, rej) {
                res(cacheObj.value); 
            });
        }

        // set the new expiry for the cache, this just adds 5 minutes to now
        cacheObj.expiry = new Date(new Date().setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes() + 5));
       
        return $http.get('Profile/IsLoggedIn').then(function (response) {
            cacheObj.value = response.data;
            return response.data; // this depends on what the response object looks like
        });
    }
});
```

You could easily encapsulate the cache into a factory with a proper `key` `value` storage api. This would extract some of the logic out of your thin service ( to keep it thin )

### Local Storage and Cookie Storage

I have used this [module](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) for years to do local storage access, this can be slotted in place of the cache *or* you could still have your cache service to wrap this storage solution so that you can completely stay decoupled from your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I can share what I do in my own apps, and although I am using ui-router, the same technique [can easily be applied to the built in router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937751/angular-how-use-one-resolve-for-all-the-routes-of-my-application/19938307#19938307).

Basic logical workflow:

1. Automatically add a `resolve` to every route that fetches the user's current auth status and caches it.
2. Check if route requires authentication, and reject if user is not logged in, otherwise allow to proceed normally.
3. On `$routeChangeError` (or something similar) check to see what action to perform.

The advantage of this is it allows you to have a great deal of flexibility with regard to providing a nice client side experience with security.

### Adding Credentials to Every Route:

```
let originalStateFunction = $stateProvider.state;

$stateProvider.state = function (state, config) {

  //
  // The "allowAnonymous" is something we added manually
  // This will become important later because we might have
  // routes that don't require authentication, like say
  // the login page
  //
  if (angular.isDefined(config) && !config.allowAnonymous) {
      _.defaults(config.resolve || (config.resolve = {}), {
          /*@ngInject*/
          userSession: function userSessionSecurityCheck($q, sessionService) {
              let def = $q.defer();        

              sessionService.getSession()
                .then(session => {
                   if(!session.isAuthenticated){
                      def.reject({
                        error:'AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED'
                      });
                   }
                });

              return def.promise;

              //You could also do more complex handling here...
              // like check permissions for specific routes
              // and reject the promise if they fail.
          }
      });
  }    

  //Now call the original state/when method with our
  // newly augmented config object
  return originalStateFunction.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

### Inspecting The Route Error

```
.run($rootScope => {
    "ngInject";

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) => {
         event.preventDefault();
         if(error.error === "AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED"){
              //Now you can redirect the user appropriately
         }
    });
});
```

You can create a simple endpoint to return the current user's status by inspecting the Principal, and so long as you are smart about caching that on the client, you will only incur the hit once per user.

The full sample code is too large for SO, but hopefully this gives you a good starting point.

Comment: One improvement you could make is that you don't need the $q because `sessionService` already uses promises!! To reject a promise just `throw` inside it!! If you `throw` an object (like you should do) this should get passed into the reject method parameters.

Comment: @CallumLinington - This is true, but then I would be using exceptions to handle application flow, which I usually try to avoid.

It's not shown here, but my logic is slightly more complex where I actually check specific permissions against a returned array, and not just `isAuthenticated`. In that way, I am able to restrict a user further.

Comment: Okay then, rather than creating a new `def` why not just do `if (!session.isAuthenticated) { return $q.reject({ error: 'AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED' }); }`

Comment: However, is it not a exceptional circumstance not to be logged in, therefor we should throw an exception!

Comment: It's not exceptional if you know it can happen :) But I do like your other idea of just using `reject`

Comment: I'm not going to try and start a heated debate or anything, I'm going to close out on this though, [dont use exceptions for flow control](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl). I would disagree that by using throw that we are controlling flow. But it is also a gray area. But to be honest, `throw` or `$q.reject` is doesn't really matter :P