# Show confirmation modal before calling $routeChangeStart in AngularJs like window onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onbeforeunload, ngroute

Im able to show a confirmation modal once route starts to change, if users selects to stay my route does not change, it stays to the original route, but loads the form directives again, which causes form to loss all its checkbox, input values. It gets reset to defaults.

If a user closes the page, i'm able to show confirmation modal, also the form state does not change. All values are retained.

Below is my code:
also, please note Im also injecting a resolve for all routes by default (this [Angular : How use one resolve for all the routes of my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937751/angular-how-use-one-resolve-for-all-the-routes-of-my-application))

After that im calling `.run()`

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
            //isLoggedIn also check URL params
            if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                $window.location.href = Auth.getLoginUrl();
            }

            ////unsaved modal start
            if ($rootScope.unsaved) {

                ngDialog.open({
                    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default unsaved-modal',
                    template: 'scripts/core/commonmodal/tplUnsavedModal.html',
                    controller: [function OpenDialogContainer() {
                        var modal = this;
                        modal.message = 'You have some unsaved changes. Do you want to leave this page?';
                        modal.stop = function () {
                            modal.processing = true;
                            ngDialog.close();
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeSuccess');
                        };
                        modal.continue = function () {
                            modal.processing = true;
                            ngDialog.close();
                            $rootScope.unsaved = false;
                            $location.path(newUrl.$$route.originalPath); //Go to page they're interested in
                        };
                    }],
                    controllerAs: 'modal'
                });
                //prevent navigation by default since we'll handle it
                //once the user selects a dialog option
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        });
```

Im setting `$rootScope.unsaved = true` if form is NOT `$pristine` and NOT `$submitted`

As you can see in the below gifvideo, on stay the route runs the controller function again. Instead what I wanted was a `window onbeforeunload` alike effect.

http://recordit.co/g5T9wWkDry.gif

Comment: I think that the problem isn't with your modal on route change, but with your form which is somehow changing into view with spinner which might also change controller.

Comment: when users chooses to stay, controller loads again. Cant I just prevent route from triggering

Comment: You can prevent route from changing, but the problem is with your submit button on form which somehow destroy current controller and switch to spinner view. Look at my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/irhabi/y71y8fxr/ . Open console, and look what happens when you change route. It's reloading controller on each route change instead of `student.profile` which I prevent. This shows that there is something wrong with your form controller, not route change/prevent.

Comment: but u have shared stateProvider @krutkowski86

Comment: OK i found out, its due to my directives they are reinitializing. But not able to figure out how do I stop scope reloading.

Comment: fixed it. had to remove this line `$rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeSuccess');` Also, made is directive instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it just by removing this line `$rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeSuccess');` also, instead I made a directive.

```
link: function($scope) {
                var message = 'You have some unsaved changes. Do you want to leave this page?';
                $window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                    if ($scope.unsavedChanges) {
                        return 'You have some unsaved changes. Do you want to leave this page?';
                    }
                };
                var $routeChangeStartUnbind = $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, newUrl) {
                    if ($scope.unsavedChanges) {
                        $rootScope.pageloaded = true;//prevent loading icon
                        ngDialog.open({
                            appendClassName: 'unsaved-modal',
                            template: 'scripts/core/commonmodal/tplUnsavedModal.html',
                            controller: [function OpenDialogContainer() {
                                var modal = this;
                                modal.message = message;
                                modal.stop = function () {
                                    modal.processing = true;
                                    ngDialog.close();
                                };
                                modal.continue = function () {

                                    modal.processing = true;
                                    ngDialog.close();
                                    $routeChangeStartUnbind();
                                    $location.path(newUrl.$$route.originalPath); //Go to page they're interested in
                                    $rootScope.pageloaded = false;
                                    $scope.unsavedChanges = false;
                                    $window.location.reload();//$route.reload() does not reload services
                                };
                            }],
                            controllerAs: 'modal'
                        });
                        //prevent navigation by default since we'll handle it
                        //once the user selects a dialog option
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });

                $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    window.onbeforeunload = null;
                    $routeChangeStartUnbind();
                });
            }
```