# angular resolve with numerous routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-services

I'm working on application which is part of family apps. Every app works with the same token but with different settings, I have wrote a piece of code which allows checks configs before loading controller and page template, but the problem is that I have around 50 routes and I don't want to duplicate it for every route. So I wonder if angular has some interceptor allows resolve my check function before loading route and don't duplicate this piece of code

P.S. of course the simple way is write factory for this and add simple line of "resolve return factory" for every route, but I'm curious if there any other way?

Next is piece of my resolve function

```
  page: 'Home Page',
        templateUrl: Config.baseURL + '/views/welcome.html',
        controller: 'welcome',
        resolve: {
            getConfig: function (lovServices) {
                var config = App.storage('App_config');
                if (config == null){
                    return lovServices.appConfig()
                        .then(function (response) {
                            App.storage('App_config', response);
                        })
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            },
            getPermissions: function (lovServices) {
                var permissions = App.storage('App_access');
                if (permissions == null){
                    return  lovServices.permissions()
                        .then(function (response) {
                            function checkAvailability(arr, val) {
                                return arr.some(function(arrVal) {
                                    return val === arrVal.allowed;
                                });
                            }
                            if (checkAvailability(response, true)){
                                var permissions = JSON.stringify(response);
                                App.storage('App_access', permissions);
                            } else {
                                localStorage.removeItem('App_token');
                                localStorage.removeItem('App_config');
                                localStorage.removeItem('App_access');
                                return false
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Angular does have intercepters which is commonly used for authentication - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @Developer I know about this interceptor and already using that if there is no token in local storage. This is not what I'm looking for

Comment: In that case I think you are looking for writing the above piece of code in route change event (`$routeChangeStart`) which would trigger in every route transitions. You can reject the transition if the check fails

Comment: @Developer have found a better way see my answer

Answer (score 0):

So based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975874/6524629) Inside of my route provider before route definitions I have put this code:

```
   function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    var originalWhen = $routeProvider.when;

    $routeProvider.when = function(path, route) {

        route.resolve || (route.resolve = {});
        angular.extend(route.resolve, {
            getConfig: function (lovServices) {
                var config = App.storage('App_config');
                if (config == null && path !== '/login'){
                    return lovServices.AppConfig()
                        .then(function (response) {
                            App.storage('App_config', response);
                        })
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            },
            getPermissions: function (lovServices) {
                var permissions = App.storage('App_access');
                if (permissions == null && path !== '/login'){
                    return  lovServices.permissions()
                        .then(function (response) {
                            function checkAvailability(arr, val) {
                                return arr.some(function(arrVal) {
                                    return val === arrVal.allowed;
                                });
                            }
                            if (checkAvailability(response, true)){
                                var permissions = JSON.stringify(response);
                                App.storage('App_access', permissions);
                            } else {
                                localStorage.removeItem('App_token');
                                localStorage.removeItem('App_config');
                                localStorage.removeItem('App_access');
                                return false
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
        });

        return originalWhen.call($routeProvider, path, route);
    };

    $routeProvider.when('/', { ....
```

This code works as I expected.